# Fluent Assertions between two collection class

Tags: c#, linq, fluent-assertions

I have a class with collection class inside

```
public class SearchResult {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string BookName { get; set; }
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        public string ISBNCode { get; set; }
        public IList<catagory> Catagories { get; set; }
}
```

I have a question , if I create the other object , with same structure of SearchResult and I want to copy SearchResult to SearchResultClone, which inside Books only copy BookId and BookName remain is empty.
Just like below

```
{
  "Id": 0,
  "Total": 3,
  "Books": [
    {
      "BookId": 1,
      "BookName": "Book A",
      "Publisher": "",
      "ISBNCode": "",
      "Catagories": []
    },
    {
      "BookId": 2,
      "BookName": "Book B",
      "Publisher": "",
      "ISBNCode": "",
      "Catagories": []
    },
    {
      "BookId": 3,
      "BookName": "Book C",
      "Publisher": "",
      "ISBNCode": "",
      "Catagories": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Event the original result have value of Publisher, ISBNCode ..etc
How to do it in LINQ ?

My second question is , if I want to make a fluent assertions as above object

```
var result = await sut.search(query);
result.Should().BeEquivalentTo ({the SearchResultClone })
```

How to write this fluent assertion ?

Comment: It's okay to ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new instances of the classes based on the old instances:

```
var ans = result.Select(sr => new SearchResult {
    Id = sr.Id,
    Total = sr.Total,
    Books = sr.Books.Select(b => new Book { BookId = b.BookId, BookName = b.BookName }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: I have success to do this by 
var result = await sut.search(query);
result.Should().BeEquivalentTo (expected) so I don't need to mapping on each one
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> result.Should().BeEquivalentTo ({the SearchResultClone })
> ```
>
> How to write this fluent assertion ?

If your expectation (the object you pass into `BeEquivalentTo`) is of the type `SearchResult`, then FA will try to compare the empty values of `ISBN` to the same property on the `sut`. You can solve that by doing something like:

```
sut.Should().BeEquivalentTo(new 
{
  Id = "some value",
  Total = 123,
  Books = new[] 
  {
    new 
    {
      BookId = 123,
      BookName = "some book"
    }
  }
});
```